# Where to store global WebMail settings in MVC3?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, events, hook

should I stored my global WebMail variables within Application_Start() event? I read creating a Base Controller is not necessary, and it makes sense because I have used hooks in MVC  architecture before. Is there a way I can simply hook these in?

e.g. WebMail.SmtpServer, WebMail.UserName, WebMail.Password, WebMail.From?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about in the web.config

```
 <system.net>
    <mailSettings>
      <smtp>
        <network 
             host="myHost" 
             port="myPortNumber"
             userName="username"
             password="password" />
      </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
  </system.net>
```